# Incorrect description of the method in the documentation (С#)

Tags: c#

When I use the double.TryParse() method to convert a string to a floating point number, the method returns false, but the documentation says everything should work

```
string message = "12.3";
double number;
bool test = double.TryParse(message, out number);

Console.WriteLine(test);
```

I tried using different floating point data types in the method, but it didn't work
But if I use "," as a decimal separator in the string everything works, although the method documentation says otherwise

```
string message = "12,3";
double number;
bool test = double.TryParse(message, out number);

Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Where can I get up-to-date information on how C# methods work?

Comment: `double.TryParse` uses your current locale for parsing. The first example will not work if your current locale uses something other than a dot for decimal numbers (as seems to be the case since it works with a comma instead)

Comment: Are you on a non- English windows by any chance?

Comment: You don't mention what documentation you are looking at. If you look at Microsoft's documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-double-tryparse(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-iformatprovider-system-double@) you will see that there are several overloads for `TryParse` that take in a format provider where you can explicitly set the culture to use for parsing.

Comment: And the documentation for the overload you're using explicitly says: "The s parameter is parsed using the formatting information in a NumberFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current system culture."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string message = "12.3";
double number;
bool test = double.TryParse(message, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);

Console.WriteLine(test); // This should print true
```